# Clicked Animation is gone after design with <shape>

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

while using a ListView to show some data to the user, By default the ListView items have a "Clicked" Animation when the user clicks them [as shown in the picture]
[image]

Now, i wanted to design the items in the ListView and added `android:background="@drawable/border"`
to their XML layout definition

when drawable/border.xml is defined to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="#000000" />
<solid android:color="#ffe5d226"/>
<padding
    android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
<corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

After doing this the ListView items changed to the shape and color that I wanted, However the "Clicked" animation was gone [I am Clicking on the "Wednesday" in the picture below]
[image]

I've been trying to solve this for a long time but with no success :\
How can I retrieve the "Clicked" Animation while keeping the Item designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to my problem was found by creating in the @drawable folder:

1) "NOT Clicked" Background layout to the ListView item named not_clicked_layout.xml 
like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="#000000" />
<solid android:color="@color/green"/>
<padding
    android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />

<corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

2) "Clicked" Background layout to the ListView item, i.e. how it will look like the moment the user pushes it. named clicked_layout.xml 
Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/gold"/>
<stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="#000000" />

<padding
    android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
<corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

3) The last and most important layout is the one that sticks the two previous steps by creating the last layout named: list_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/not_clicked_layout" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/clicked_layout" />

</selector>
```

The above layout declares the "not_clicked_layout.xml" to be shown when the item is NOT pressed, and "clicked_layout" to be shown when the item is pressed.

4) All that is left to do is to add:

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

to the layout of your ListView Item and the "Clicked" Animation will arise from the dead :)

**Note**: this Solution is relevant not only to ListView items, but to any GUI element you would like to create a "Pushed" Animation.